# Token for Facebook Business SDK in Python Script used as Cronjob

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-python-business-sdk, facebook-business-sdk

I try to run a python script as a cronjob on my server using the [facebook business sdk](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-python-business-sdk). The purpose of the script is to get a random product of our shop and to publish a post, promoting the product from the shop.

To do so, I need the page permissions for `manage_pages` and `publish_pages`. All this works fine while the app is in development but when I try to use it in live modus, the token does not get accepted. I tried to get a new token, but as I understand it, I can't get the permissions unless I request an *App Review*.

Did I get this right?

And how to do so for a simple python script that runs on my server as a cronjob?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You're right that you need to do an App Review to get the permissions to work in production. We've run into the same issue, all of our stuff is through cron jobs where we already have access to the accounts and access tokens for every account, but we didn't have permissions. We contacted Facebook and they said in order to get the permissions we need to do a full App Review.